# Can we typecast the application context get bean as Class<?>

Tags: java, spring

In my application I want to load dynamic classes. I added the code snippet like below,

```
private static Class clazz;
```

In the method of the implemented class,

```
clazz = (Class) applicationContext.getBean("arrived class name for thirty party");
```

Is approach valid to get the class in the application?

Answer (score 1):

if its object reistered and you need class name of that bean

```
clazz = applicationContext.getBean("arrived class name for thirty party").getClass();
```

if its String value registered as bean and you need its class instance

```
clazz = Class.forName(applicationContext.getBean("arrived class name for thirty party"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use - clazz = applicationContext.getBean("arrived class name for thirty party",.class);

ex- Employee emp = ctx.getBean("arrived class name for thirty party", Employee.class);